# how to Unicode result in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I try to make program to submit any word to (http://upodn.com/phon.php) using BeautifulSoup then print the result.
for example when i submit the "hello" word to (http://upodn.com/phon.php) website the result is: `həlo`
but when i submit the "hello" word using my script it the result is: `h&#x0259;lo`

How i can print the result as its appear in the website => `həlo` ?

Script:

```
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import mechanize
import cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import html2text

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1'), ('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')]
br.open('http://upodn.com/phon.php')
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['intext'] = 'hello'
br.submit()
data = br.response().read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
# print soup
table = soup.find('table', {'rules': 'cols'})
result = []
for row in table.findAll("font"):
    d = row.text
    result.append(d)
print result[1]
```

output:

```
h&#x0259;lo
[Finished in 2.7s]
```

Comment: First of all, you're using the obsolete version of BeautifulSoup; the current version is the package and module `bs4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using absolutely obsolete version of BeautifulSoup, BeautifulSoup 3. The current version, BeautifulSoup 4 is called [`beautifulsoup4`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4) in PyPI and has top-level package `bs4`. BeautifulSoup 4 decodes these html entities:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> print(BeautifulSoup('<b>h&#x0259;lo</b>').find('b').text)
həlo
```

There is no point in writing new code that uses BeautifulSoup3, so you should switch now.